# Python - Flask - Google Charts API Get The Value in each CategoryFilter and pass it to the href

Tags: javascript, python, flask, google-visualization

I have a table created using GoogleCharts API with multiple CategoryFilters, like below.

[image: before filtering]

After filtering out the data, I would like to retrieve all the values in each filter.

[image: after filtering]

The url of the current page is `home/`. So if I click on the `NEXT button`, I want to navigate to the next page, which is `home/GT/ALL/ALL/ALL/ALL/`.

Now I am confused how to retrieve the value in each filter and write them down in the href.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="button" href="#">NEXT</button> <!--how to get the value from each filter and pass them on the href?-->
</div>
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATED**

I tried to simplify my problem. So I am in `/home/` page. The page looks like below.

[image]

I choose a value from the filter, for example I chose `A`.

[image]

Then if I hit `NEXT` button, it will take me to the next page with the url `/home/A`.

The HTML looks like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table', 'controls']});

      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(createTableWithFilter);

      function createTableWithFilter() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Type', 'Value'],
                    ['A', 1],
                    ['A', 2],
                    ['B', 1],
                    ['B', 2]
                    ]);

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        var categoryFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
             'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
             'containerId': 'filter_div',
             'options': {
                 'filterColumnLabel': 'Type'
             }
        });

        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'Table',
            'containerId': 'table_div',
        });


        dashboard.bind(categoryFilter, table);
        dashboard.draw(data);

      }

    </script>

    <style>
        .btn-group .button {
            background-color: #008CBA;
            color: white;
            padding: 7px 16px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        .btn-group .button:not(:last-child) {
            border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
        }
        .btn-group .button:hover {
            background-color: #195389;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
        <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
        <div id="filter_div"></div>
        <div id="table_div"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="button" href="#">NEXT PAGE</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort
import os

tmpl_dir = 'templates'
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=tmpl_dir)


@app.route("/")
def index():    
    return render_template('example_get_value_from_categoryfilter.html')      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

How to get the value `A` from the selected option in the CategoryFilter and pass it to the `href` in the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each filter has a `state` property

use the `getState()` method to retrieve the `selectedValues` of the filter...

`selectedValues` will be an array of one or more selected values

```
categoryFilter.getState().selectedValues
```

using jquery, you could update the href with something like...

```
if (categoryFilter.getState().selectedValues.length > 0) {
  $('.button').attr('href', categoryFilter.getState().selectedValues[0]);
}
```

**EDIT**

you'll also need to use the `'statechange'` event to know when a filter has occurred

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    createTableWithFilter();
    window.addEventListener('resize', createTableWithFilter, false);
  },
  packages: ['table', 'controls']
});

function createTableWithFilter() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Type', 'Value'],
    ['A', 1],
    ['A', 2],
    ['B', 1],
    ['B', 2]
  ]);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  var categoryFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Type'
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryFilter, 'statechange', function () {
    var urlAddr = '/home';

    categoryFilter.getState().selectedValues.forEach(function (filterValue) {
      urlAddr += '/' + filterValue;
    });
    $('.button').attr('href', urlAddr);

    console.log($('.button').attr('href'));
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'table_div',
  });

  dashboard.bind(categoryFilter, table);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="table_div"></div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="button" href="#">NEXT</a> <!--how to get the value from each filter and pass them on the href?-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am not an expert in HTML, yet I will give it a try. Hope it will work. Once again, thanks and will come back again after testing it.

Comment: I just updated my original post. If you do not mind, could you point out how to incorporate your suggestion in my case? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for editing your post. If I run the code in the snippet, indeed I could see `/home/A` or `/home/B` or `/home/A/B` or `/home/B/A`. However, the `home/A` (or `/home/B` and so forth) does not assign to the `NEXT` button. If I click the button, it does not navigate me to the next page. Any idea? Once again, thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: silly me! Thanks your code is working! It is my fault. I surrounded the button with `<button </button>` tag instead of `<a </a>` tag. Kindly edit your post, and I will mark it as the right answer. Again, thanks a ton!